# how to remove a column from Pandas dataframe using Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code (Python 2.7):

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
pages = [i for i in range(1, int(math.ceil(reports.get_reports_count()/page_size)+1))]
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=len(pages)) as executor:
    futh = [executor.submit(reports.fill_dataframe, page) for page in pages]
    for data in as_completed(futh):
        df = df.append(data.result(), ignore_index=True)
cuttent_time = datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df["timestamp"] = cuttent_time
df.columns = [c.lower().replace(' ', '_') for c in df.columns]
df = df.replace(r'\n', ' ', regex=True)
file_name = "{0}.csv.gz".format(tab_name)
df.to_csv(path_or_buf=file_name, index=False, encoding='utf-8',
          compression='gzip',
          quoting=QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
```

This creates a compressed csv file from the data stream. 
Now, I want to make sure that the column in the file are the ones I expect (order does not matter). Meaning that if for any reason the data stream contains more columns than this columns will be removed. Note that I add a column of my own to the data stream called `timestamp`.

The allowed columns are:

```
cols_list = ['order_id', 'customer_id', 'date', 'price']
```

I'm aware that there is `del df['column_name']` option but this doesn't work for me as I have no idea what will be the redundant column name.

I'm looking for something like:

```
if col_name not it cols_list:
   del df[???]  #delete column and it's data.
   print [???]  #print the name of the redundant column for log
```

I think there are two approaches here:

1. not to add the redundant column to the `df` in the first place.
2. remove the redundant column after the `df.append` is finished.

I prefer the 1st option as it should be with better performance (?)

One of my attempts was:

```
for i, data in enumerate(df):
        for col_name in cols_list:
            if col_name not in data.keys():
               del df[col_name ]
```

but it doesn't work..

> if col_name not in data.keys(): AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'

I'm not sure I enumerate over `df` itself

Comment: why not just get a new dataframe that will have the desired columns from the previous dataframe and a new one that you have added. That way if there are more columns in the previous dataframe it is immaterial as you will be only dealing with the required columns in the new dataframe

Comment: @Inder I'm not sure I'm following you. I can't compere the previous CSV to the current one. I delete them after the code is finished. The csv is a step towards uploading the data into BigQuery.

Comment: what I am saying is that you only need order id, customer id , date, price say from a dataframe df(1) , that can have say 10 columns . just create an empty dataframe df(2), assign the columns that you need from df(1) eg df(2)["customer id"] = df(1)["customer id"] . Also u can add your custom column to this new dataframe and do as you desire with it you can be sure that it only has the required columns regardless of what the original data frame had

Comment: @Inder that might be a huge consumption of memory and time... Isn't there another way? What about doing the  df.append only for the desired columns?

Comment: append will throw an error if the number of columns are different.

Comment: on similar grounds you can also take columns from the old dataframe without creating anew dataframe, eg : there is a dataframe df with 10 columns suppose you only need two of these (date and price) just do a df=df[["date","price"]] 
it will be faster than the previous approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make your attempt with `for loop` works, try this:

```
for col_name in df.columns:
    if col_name not in cols_list:
       del df[col_name]
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the redundant column after the `df.append` is finished is quite simple:

```
df = df[cols_list]
```

As for the first suggestion, you could apply the statement described above before appending it to the `df`. However, you should note that this requires a `pandas DataFrame` object, so you would probably need to transform the `data.result()` to a pandas Dataframe first.

Comment: cols_list are the columns that should stay. I don't know the names of the columns that I need to remove. Everything that is not on cols_list should be removed.

Comment: Yes, if you apply the function that I gave, it will only take the columns specified in cols_list to the new `df` variable.

Comment: this doesn't answer my question :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the Pandas documentation for the function read_csv at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html there is a parameter 'usecols' which is described:

> usecols : list-like or callable, default None
>
> Return a subset of the columns. If list-like, all elements must either
>   be positional (i.e. integer indices into the document columns) or
>   strings that correspond to column names provided either by the user in
>   names or inferred from the document header row(s). For example, a
>   valid list-like usecols parameter would be [0, 1, 2] or [‘foo’, ‘bar’,
>   ‘baz’]. Element order is ignored, so usecols=[0, 1] is the same as [1,
>   0]. To instantiate a DataFrame from data with element order preserved
>   use pd.read_csv(data, usecols=['foo', 'bar'])[['foo', 'bar']] for
>   columns in ['foo', 'bar'] order or pd.read_csv(data, usecols=['foo',
>   'bar'])[['bar', 'foo']] for ['bar', 'foo'] order.
>
> If callable, the callable function will be evaluated against the
>   column names, returning names where the callable function evaluates to
>   True. An example of a valid callable argument would be lambda x:
>   x.upper() in ['AAA', 'BBB', 'DDD']. Using this parameter results in
>   much faster parsing time and lower memory usage.

This is the answer to your problem.

Comment: This is not a solution. First you assume that I do read_csv which is wrong. I upload the file to Google Storage and update BigQuery with it. Second, There could be more than 20 columns that I need to ignore.. assuming 500K rows per file that it a lot of space which used for nothing, not to mention the process time.

Comment: Then I suggest that the at least the title needs to be changed, it specifically mentions csv. But I would also point out that you must have criteria for excluding columns and presumably these can be coded so you may want to use the callable version of something like this parameter, it can be a function.

Answer (score 0):

I think need [`intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.intersection.html) by list of `column names`s and then filter by `subset` with `[]`:

```
cols_list = ['order_id', 'customer_id', 'date', 'price']
cols = df.columns.intersection(cols_list)
df = df[cols]
```